# Code Cells are not displaying in Print Preview in Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, jupyter-irkernel

I have a ipynb jupyter notebook file with content, image, python code and markdown.
While print preview my ipynb file, it is rendering all data perfectly except python code cell.

Checked all settings and config. Could not able to find exact issue.
Need help for it .

Checked using Inspect element , for the cell contains python code div element is blank as well.